# c++ boost asio post requests

Tags: c++, post, boost, asio

I need to send several post requests to my virtual machine. I get examples of packets from pcap file and then modify them to insert my data(I do it because format of data is rather strange). At first, I send an empty post request (variable none) to my server and everything is OK, server responds to me. But then I need to send another post request(variable challenge_responce), but when I do it as the first time, server doesn't responses me.

```
none = "POST /jsproxy HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.37.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: file://
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/44.0.2403.89 Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: username=admin"
```

```
challenge_responce = "POST /jsproxy HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.37.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 117
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: file://
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/44.0.2403.89 Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: username=admin

ДЂДЂДЂДЂДЂДЂДЂ/RГ±В±В•Г‚$0[^96В“Г№В¦ДЂДЂ!@#$%^&*()_+:3|~ДЂДЂДЂДЂДЂДЂДЂДЂВ§Г‡1&TВЌВЌpMГЇm)[4}(В¤<HГѓ%Гў(Г„Гadmin"
```

Here is my code:

```
packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
Arrcpy(none, ParsePacket(packet, length), 1000);

packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
Arrcpy(challenge, ParsePacket(packet, length), 1000);

packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
Arrcpy(challenge_responce, ParsePacket(packet, length), 1000);

boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("192.168.37.2", "http");

stream << none;

std::string temp;
std::string chPacket;
auto t = stream.rdbuf();
while (std::getline(stream, temp))
    chPacket += temp;

auto code = GetChallenge(chPacket);

std::string modChallengeResponce = ModifyChallengeResponce(challenge_responce, length, code, "qazwsx12");

stream << modChallengeResponce;
std::string resq;

while (std::getline(stream, temp))
    resq += temp;

std::cout << stream.rdbuf();
```

How can i fix it?? May be I shoule not use tcp::iostream ??

Comment: Beast library is using asio and is special for HTTP stuff.

Comment: i understand, but how can i do it correctly??

Comment: Your samples don't show how you encode the requests. From the looks of it you don't adhere to HTTP requirements (e.g. using CRLF line-ends). And since your binary (?) data doesn't fit in the ASCII7 subset you will depend on how your editor encodes that (presumably that will be how you opened the binary stuff, so likely misinterpreted as UTF8). Just... Do HTTP properly. Many tutorials exist. And, yes you can use a library for that (curl, Boost Beast, maybe)

Comment: Thank you, I form my requests properly, \r\n at the end of each line, and \r\n\r\n before data, the problem is that my programm doesn't send second packet at all. I am sure that i send a packet from variable none correctly, but when i try to send the second one, my program doesn't send it at all